# How would one place a big float (figure and caption) in the whole page occupying the entire text area

Tags: graphics, floats, header-footer, rotating, sidewaysfigure

I have a massive flow-diagram describing a new methodology we developed. Despite the combined efforts of my supervisor and mine, we could not split the diagram into two parts.

It was decided that the entire unbroken figure is required to explain the concept. Luckily, I created the figure as a vector graphic (a PDF) and also created it close to paper-measurements so that text within boxes and other labels are readable.

Now, in my thesis on a A4-sized paper, I wish to include this figure (in a 90 degree rotated placement). To make the maximum use of available spacing, I wish to get rid of the header.

- the page itself should remain in portrait mode
- only the inserted graphic (.pdf file) should be rotated 90 degrees.
- finally, we just need a normal caption, i.e. caption should not be rotated.

How can I achieve this?

I got up to this `MNWE`, but still needs more work to get to the final desired result.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\mpfootnotes}[1][1]{
  \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\thefootnote}
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-#1}
  \renewcommand{\footnote}{\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext[\value{footnote}]}}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}  % trying to get rid of header to reduce visual clutter on this float page
\begin{figure}[p]      % the figure needs to occupy the entire page. Hence permitting only the 'p' modifier. 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\textwidth]{demo} % 'fig_master_flow_diagramPDF.pdf' is a huge figure and needs to stretch/shrink suitably to occupy the entire type-area available.
        \caption
        [%
        Interesting caption
        ]%
        {%
             Interesting caption\footnotemark.
        }%
        \label{fig:fig_strategy_schematic}
        \mpfootnotes[1]
        \footnote{Some important footnote}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the aspect ration, or expand to the limits of the text area?

Comment: @JohnKormylo   I would like to preserve the aspect ratio, center the figure both horizontally and vertically, and use the full available width (upto the left and right margins)

Comment: your example produces undefined command errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for pointing this out. I have updated the MWE. My goal is not to rotate the caption, but only the graphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version which uses the entire text area.  To preserve the aspect ratio, I would have to know which dimension is the limiting factor.

The page should print normally, but appear rotated when viewing the PDF.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}% for \captionof
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% debug only

\newcommand{\mpfootnotes}[1][1]{
  \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\thefootnote}
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-#1}
  \renewcommand{\footnote}{\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext[\value{footnote}]}}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{% wait for top of next apge
\begin{landscape}% automatic \clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}% trying to get rid of header to reduce visual clutter on this float page
\sbox0{\begin{minipage}{\textheight}% compute height of caption and footnote
        \null\captionof{figure}
        [%
        Interesting caption
        ]%
        {%
             Interesting caption\footnotemark.
        }%
        \label{fig:fig_strategy_schematic}
        \mpfootnotes[1]
        \footnote{Some important footnote}
    \end{minipage}}%
\noindent\parbox[c][\textheight][c]{\linewidth}{\centering
  \rotatebox[origin=Bc]{-90}{\usebox0}%
  \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width={\dimexpr \linewidth-\ht0-\dp0},height=\textheight]{example-image}}}
\end{landscape}}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

---

Here is the same page without using pdflscape.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}% for \captionof
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% debug only

\newcommand{\mpfootnotes}[1][1]{
  \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\thefootnote}
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-#1}
  \renewcommand{\footnote}{\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext[\value{footnote}]}}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{% wait for top of next apge
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}% trying to get rid of header to reduce visual clutter on this float page
\sbox0{\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}% compute height of caption and footnote
        \leavevmode\captionof{figure}
        [%
        Interesting caption
        ]%
        {%
             Interesting caption\footnotemark.
        }%
        \label{fig:fig_strategy_schematic}
        \mpfootnotes[1]
        \footnote{Some important footnote}
    \end{minipage}}%
\noindent\parbox[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}{\centering
\includegraphics[angle=90,width=\textwidth,height={\dimexpr \textheight-\ht0-\dp0}]{example-image}
\usebox0}
\clearpage}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am so sorry. I did not make the question clear. What I meant was, the page itself should remain in portrait, while the figure should be rotated 90 degrees. We need a normal caption, i.e. caption should not be rotated. I have updated the question to clarify these.

Comment: I created two versions, one using pdflscape and one without.  I also centered the contents on the page, should one of the dimensions drop below the limit.

Answer (score 2):

With a big image it's often best to position it "by eye" By using picture mode you can move it anywhere on the page without disturbing the other text or getting over full box warnings, just adjust the size of the picture, the coordinate and size of the image to fit your real image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\mpfootnotes}[1][1]{%%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-#1}%%
  \renewcommand{\footnote}{\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext[\value{footnote}]}}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}  % trying to get rid of header to reduce visual clutter on this float page
\begin{figure}[p]      % the figure needs to occupy the entire page. Hence permitting only the 'p' modifier. 
\begin{picture}(0,570)
\put(-50,0){%
        \includegraphics[angle=90,width=.85\paperwidth]{example-image}
}
\end{picture}

        \caption
        [%
        Interesting caption
        ]%
        {%
             Interesting caption\footnotemark.
        }%
        \label{fig:fig_strategy_schematic}
        \mpfootnotes[1]
        \footnote{Some important footnote}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ,this seems to rely on eyeballing placement positions. Isn't there some automatic way to center the figure on the page?

Comment: sure but the point of the answer here is not to do it automatically, but to manually adjust to what looks best, this is like italic correction or microtype's protrusion, what looks right by eye, and what is mathematically centred according to its bounding box are not always the same thing,