# Fit (vertically portrayed) image with the caption displayed below

Tags: graphics, formatting

So I have this code:

```
     \begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=\textheight, width=\textwidth]{similar_waveforms_filtered_and_cut_new}  
\caption{Seiemic traces for events studied in this project with picks made at station DE02 - the closest station to the locations determined.}
\label{similar_waveforms}  
\end{figure}
```

and I am trying to 'best fit' an image that I have rotated so that it is portrayed vertically. 
when I am using height=\textheight, width=\textwidth my caption appears below the footnote - is there a way to correct this? 
I have attached an image for reference[image: seismic_waves]. 
Many Thanks

Comment: welcome to tex.se! you need to reduce image height for amount of caption (~ 3\`baselineskip`).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449301/how-would-one-place-a-big-float-figure-and-caption-in-the-whole-page-occupying

Answer (score 4):

as mentioned in my comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
     \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\textheight-3\baselineskip, % <---
                 width=\textwidth,
                 keepaspectio]%
                {similar_waveforms_filtered_and_cut_new}
\caption{Seiemic traces for events studied in this project with picks made at station DE02 - the closest station to the locations determined.}
\label{similar_waveforms}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @HB, if answer solve your problem, you can accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of the answer ;-)

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to add a `\keepaspectio` option to `\includegraphics`. While it doesn't make a difference for the black rectangle that's used in your answer, it's probably a good thing to have in general.

Comment: @Mico, you are right. corrected.