# How to rotate effectively this regression table in landscape?

Tags: tables, landscape

Currently I am using this code for landscape:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Throwing everything in the table and rotating it to fit the page} \label{reg6}
\resizebox{1.2\textwidth}{!}{
      \estauto{Reg6.tex}{15}{c}
      }
\vspace{1em}
\small{\textit{Note:}  *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.10. All regressions control for month fixed effects to capture seasonal variations.}    
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

How can I fix it to fit perfectly to the margins?

[image]

The Reg6.tex contains the following code:

```
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Deaths}                 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Cases}                  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Tests}                  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Vaccines}               \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}         \\
\midrule
Stringency Index    &       0.034\sym{***}&       0.034\sym{***}&       2.406\sym{**} &       2.111\sym{**} &       0.026\sym{***}&       0.025\sym{**} &      -0.137         &      -0.112         \\
                    &     (0.011)         &     (0.012)         &     (1.017)         &     (0.887)         &     (0.009)         &     (0.010)         &     (0.121)         &     (0.111)         \\
\addlinespace
L4.Stringency Index &       0.006         &      -0.000         &       0.081         &       0.009         &      -0.002         &      -0.001         &      -0.084         &      -0.141         \\
                    &     (0.005)         &     (0.004)         &     (0.082)         &     (0.167)         &     (0.004)         &     (0.003)         &     (0.082)         &     (0.127)         \\
\addlinespace
L8.Stringency Index &       0.004\sym{***}&       0.006\sym{**} &      -0.136         &      -0.068         &       0.001         &       0.000         &       0.035         &       0.059         \\
                    &     (0.001)         &     (0.003)         &     (0.084)         &     (0.165)         &     (0.003)         &     (0.002)         &     (0.044)         &     (0.055)         \\
\addlinespace
L12.Stringency Index&       0.010\sym{*}  &       0.005\sym{***}&       0.106         &       0.028         &       0.003         &       0.005\sym{**} &       0.113\sym{***}&       0.087\sym{**} \\
                    &     (0.006)         &     (0.001)         &     (0.083)         &     (0.117)         &     (0.002)         &     (0.002)         &     (0.041)         &     (0.034)         \\
\addlinespace
L16.Stringency Index&       0.004         &       0.008\sym{**} &      -0.152         &      -0.129         &       0.005         &       0.002         &       0.288\sym{*}  &       0.356\sym{*}  \\
                    &     (0.003)         &     (0.004)         &     (0.294)         &     (0.285)         &     (0.007)         &     (0.004)         &     (0.171)         &     (0.193)         \\
\addlinespace
Age 65+ (years)     &                     &       0.202\sym{***}&                     &       6.660\sym{***}&                     &       0.060\sym{**} &                     &       0.024         \\
                    &                     &     (0.048)         &                     &     (1.772)         &                     &     (0.026)         &                     &     (0.188)         \\
\addlinespace
GDP per capita      &                     &      -0.278         &                     &     112.903\sym{***}&                     &       8.233\sym{***}&                     &       4.055         \\
                    &                     &     (0.530)         &                     &    (19.723)         &                     &     (1.043)         &                     &     (6.260)         \\
\addlinespace
Life expectancy (years)&                     &      -0.001         &                     &      -0.529         &                     &      -0.086\sym{*}  &                     &      -0.120         \\
                    &                     &     (0.042)         &                     &     (1.821)         &                     &     (0.048)         &                     &     (0.435)         \\
\addlinespace
Extreme poverty (\%)&                     &       0.009\sym{*}  &                     &       0.201\sym{*}  &                     &      -0.001         &                     &      -0.255\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &     (0.005)         &                     &     (0.114)         &                     &     (0.005)         &                     &     (0.078)         \\
\addlinespace
Pop. density (pop/km$^2$)&                     &      -0.001         &                     &      -0.014         &                     &       0.001         &                     &       0.005         \\
                    &                     &     (0.001)         &                     &     (0.023)         &                     &     (0.001)         &                     &     (0.004)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &      -0.863\sym{***}&      -2.094         &      -4.649         &     -26.041         &       0.578         &       4.572         &     -12.715         &      -7.872         \\
                    &     (0.162)         &     (2.287)         &    (15.788)         &   (100.542)         &     (0.412)         &     (3.001)         &     (9.217)         &    (23.173)         \\
\midrule
Obs.                &       52174         &       35214         &       56603         &       38113         &       30588         &       23812         &        1918         &        1463         \\
Controls            &          No         &         Yes         &          No         &         Yes         &          No         &         Yes         &          No         &         Yes         \\
```

Comment: Try with the package `rotating` and the environment "\begin{sidewaystable}....\end{sidewaystable}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Unless you want to use pdflscape, then use `\rotatebox` from the adjustbox package.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449301/how-would-one-place-a-big-float-figure-and-caption-in-the-whole-page-occupying/449321?r=SearchResults&s=2|21.2662#449321 for example.

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Also, how are `\estauto` and `\sym` defined?

Comment: Your table is taller than it is wide. Why do you want to put it onto a landscape page, whose text block is significantly wider than tall?