# I have a big figure with long caption, how could I put the caption in the next page?

Tags: floats, captions

I have a big figure with long caption, how could I put the caption in the next page?

My code is:

```
   \documentclass{report}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
   \usepackage{setspace}% for\doublespacing
   \usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
    \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{textalpha}
   \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
   \usepackage{xltabular} 
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{caption}
   \begin{document}  
   \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{MBPsd.jpg}
    \caption{ Social defeat stress increased MBP expression in the CA1 radiatum layer. A. the hilus, B. intensity in the hilus (Control: 3011.4 ± 72.9 (a.u.), SD: 3025.4 ± 71.1 (a.u.)), C. MBP+ area in the hilus (Control: 78.8 ± 0.3 (a.u.), SD: 78.8 ± 1.4 (\%)), D. the DG molecular layer, E. intensity in the DG molecular layer (Control: 1793.2 ± 57.6 (a.u.), SD: 1908.5 ± 65.1 (a.u.)), F. MBP+ area in the DG molecular layer (Control: 63.5 ± 1.8 (\%), SD: 62.7 ± 7.6 (\%)), G. the lacunosum moleculare, H. intensity in the lacunosum moleculare (Control: 3174.8 ± 77.1 (a.u.), SD: 3175.5 ± 106.7 (a.u.)), I. MBP+ area in the lacunosum moleculare (Control: 74.4 ± 1.3 (\%), SD: 71.9 ± 1.6 (\%)), J. the CA1 radiatum layer, K. intensity in the CA1 radiatum layer (Control: 1694.9 ± 47.6 (a.u.), SD: 1653.6 ± 80.8 (a.u.)), L. MBP+ area in the CA1 radiatum layer (Control: 19.5 ± 0.5 (\%), SD: 23.3 ± 1.5 (\%), effect-size: r = 0.34, *: p<0.01 by t-test), M. the CA1 oriens layer, N. intensity in the CA1 oriens layer (Control: 2126.2 ± 52.5 (a.u.), SD: 2033.0 ± 71.1 (a.u.)), O. MBP+ area in the CA1 oriens layer (Control: 38.5 ± 1.1 (\%), SD: 36.5 ± 1.3 (\%)), P. the mossy fibers, Q. intensity in the mossy fibers (Control: 3179.6 ± 68.5 (a.u.), SD: 3252.1 ± 63.6 (a.u.)), R. MBP+ area in the mossy fibers (Control: 77.3 ± 1.6 (\%), SD: 78.2 ± 1.5 (\%)). Control (open): n = 8, SD (black): n = 20. mean ± SEM}
    \label{MBPsd}
     \end{figure}
     \end{document}
```

Figure:[image]

Comment: Posible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449301/how-would-one-place-a-big-float-figure-and-caption-in-the-whole-page-occupying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you load the `caption` package, I suggest you make use of its `\ContinuedFloat` macro to tie the two parts of the figure together. At the bottom of the first float page, below the graphic, I'd provide a very brief (1 or 2 lines max) caption. In the second float, I'd first execute a `\ContinuedFloat` statement and then provide the legend for the graphs on the preceding page. Do consider providing paragraph breaks in the long legend; this will greatly help your readers in their attempt to take in the information you're giving them, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{report} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}  

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight,
                 keepaspectratio]{MBPsd.jpg}
\caption{Social defeat stress increased MBP expression in
  the CA1 radiatum layer. See following page for legend.}
\label{MBPsd}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\ContinuedFloat
Legend for graphs in Figure \thefigure.  

\smallskip
A. The hilus; B.~Intensity in the hilus (Control: 3011.4 ± 72.9 (a.u.), SD: 3025.4 ± 71.1 (a.u.)); C.~MBP+ area in the hilus (Control: 78.8 ± 0.3 (a.u.), SD: 78.8 ± 1.4 (\%)). 

D. The DG molecular layer; E.~Intensity in the DG molecular layer (Control: 1793.2 ± 57.6 (a.u.), SD: 1908.5 ± 65.1 (a.u.)); F.~MBP+ area in the DG molecular layer (Control: 63.5 ± 1.8 (\%), SD: 62.7 ± 7.6 (\%)). 

G. The lacunosum moleculare; H.~Intensity in the lacunosum moleculare (Control: 3174.8 ± 77.1 (a.u.), SD: 3175.5 ± 106.7 (a.u.)); I.~MBP+ area in the lacunosum moleculare (Control: 74.4 ± 1.3 (\%), SD: 71.9 ± 1.6 (\%)). 

J. The CA1 radiatum layer; K.~Intensity in the CA1 radiatum layer (Control: 1694.9 ± 47.6 (a.u.), SD: 1653.6 ± 80.8 (a.u.)); L.~MBP+ area in the CA1 radiatum layer (Control: 19.5 ± 0.5 (\%), SD: 23.3 ± 1.5 (\%), effect-size: $r = 0.34$, *: $p<0.01$ by t-test). 

M. The CA1 oriens layer; N.~Intensity in the CA1 oriens layer (Control: 2126.2 ± 52.5 (a.u.), SD: 2033.0 ± 71.1 (a.u.)); O.~MBP+ area in the CA1 oriens layer (Control: 38.5 ± 1.1 (\%), SD: 36.5 ± 1.3 (\%)). 

P. The mossy fibers; Q.~Intensity in the mossy fibers (Control: 3179.6 ± 68.5 (a.u.), SD: 3252.1 ± 63.6 (a.u.)); R.~MBP+ area in the mossy fibers (Control: 77.3 ± 1.6 (\%), SD: 78.2 ± 1.5 (\%)).

Control (open): $n = 8$, SD (black): $n = 20$. mean ± SEM

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple: put the image in a figure float but without caption, and then another figure float with the caption but without the image. Depending on  the image size, caption size, desired place for the caption,   **and influence of another floats**, you must set the floats options carefully  to ensure that the first float will be alone in an odd page, and  the next float will jump to the next even page. In the next MWE the options could be  `[t!]` and `[t]` respectively, or `[p]`  and `[t]` if you want avoid the main text under the figure (very ugly in this case, but maybe acceptable for images taking about 1/2-1/3 of the text area).

The caption is colored to remark its position on in the screenshot, not at all a suggestion of style. `;)`

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-5]
\begin{figure}[t!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{VhOBF.jpg}
\color{blue}\hfill(lengend on next page)
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{\color{blue}\sffamily\lipsum[16]}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[6-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really hepful!